# javascript form submit return value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to simulate a post request by creating form elements on the fly and then using the submit() function. I don't know how to capture the response from the server for the post request. I am making a cross domain post request.

Anything after the submit() call does not get executed. How can i capture the response to the submit() call? What is the return value of the submit() function? Any link to the api documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no return value. If you want to get values back from the server, use Ajax.

Comment: Ajax fails since cross domain requests are not allowed.

Comment: You never said you were doing this cross-domain. In that case, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submit()` stops all execution on the current page while it waits for a new page to be sent from the server.

If you want to do something AFTER submit(), you should consider using AJAX-based techniques.

Comment: Trying with ajax gives me this error - "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: That's correct. You cannot use a browser to interact with an external site that way. You did not state this requirement in your question.

Comment: edited my question. Sorry for the misunderstanding. So i guess i will have to go php/curl way.

Comment: seems the current browsers do allow cross domain ajax requests (with caveats) - http://goo.gl/SQQu7

Comment: They do, but that requires the cooperation of the third-party site.

Answer (score 1):

The script stops execution because the browser exits the page once the form is submitted (in order to go to the form's "action" page). The ways to do something after the form is submitted is to do the response logic on the form's action page or using AJAX to keep on the page once the server has responded.